# Как обрабатывать нажатие на кнопки мыши в PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, мышь

Я пишу приложение, которое обрабатывает нажатие на кнопки клавиатуры и мыши, после чего подсвечивает нажатую кнопку.

Для обработки нажатия на кнопки клавиатуры я использовал `QtKey` и `keyboard` (для работы в фоне).

Но как мне обрабатывать нажатие на кнопки мыши (так же должно работать в фоне)?

Форма: https://pastebin.com/bu72R10W

Код: https://pastebin.com/0nwdHFA4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Qt* обнаруживает только щелчок внутри виджета, если вы хотите обнаруживать вне виджетов,
тогда вы должны использовать другую библиотеку, которая использует ресурсы ОС для мониторинга событий ОС, например `pyinput` .

```
import sys
from pynput import mouse                                  # pip install pynput
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ButtonReleaseManager(QtCore.QObject):
    released = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=self._handle_click)
        self._listener.start()

    def _handle_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if not pressed:
            self.released.emit(x, y)


class Release_check(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.manager = ButtonReleaseManager()
        self.manager.released.connect(self.show_position)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 400, 100)

        self.text_out = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(self.text_out, 0, 1, 1, 2)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def show_position(self, x, y):
        screen_coordinate = f"x:{x}, y:{x}"
        self.text_out.setText(screen_coordinate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Release_check()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да все работает, но почему то при нажатии лкм курсор начинает виснуть и впринципе винда помирает, это возможно исправить?